# Could you explain the syntax of math in a bash shell?

Tags: bash, for-loop, math

```
for i in {1..99}
do
  if ([ $((i % 2)) -eq 1 ])
  then
      echo $i
  fi
done
```

I'm learning bash, and I'm trying to better understand line 3. Why does `$((i % 2))` have to be double wrapped in parenthesis, and why can't I put the `$` symbole inside next to the `i` like:

```
([ (($i % 2)) -eq 1 ])
```

or

```
([ ($(i % 2)) -eq 1 ])
```

?

Comment: Single parentheses are used to execute commands in a subshell.

Comment: Using `if ([ ... ])` is very odd.  The outer parentheses are not needed.

Comment: As a general rule, shell syntax is *extremely* context-dependent. The syntax you can use inside `$(( ))` (and a few other other "arithmetic" contexts) is very different from what you can use elsewhere.

Comment: As Barmar said single parentheses are used to execute commands in a subshell and usefull to store output of commands in vars like so `var=$(ls /home)` And if you want to do some math you should use double `$((a+b))` or square `$[a+b]` You can actualy put `$` inside but it's redundant here. Test statements after if should be in single or double(better) square parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything inside `$((...))` is treated as an arithmetic expression. You can use parameter expansion inside an arithmetic expression, but a bare string is interpreted as a variable whose (integer) value is used. You can write

```
if [ $(( i % 2 )) -eq 1 ]
```

to check if `i` is odd. You can also check for equality inside the expression, as `$(( x == y ))` evaluates to 1 if `x == y` and 0 otherwise, but you would still have to compare *that* value to something.

In `bash`, you can use the arithmetic *command*, which has an exit status of 0 if the resulting value is non-zero, and 1 otherwise. This lets you write

```
if (( i % 2 == 1 )); then
```

Comment: So to directly answer the question, you can't use `(($i % 2))` or `($(i % 2))` to do math because neither of them are on the form `$((...))`.

Comment: Well, you *can* use `(( $i % 2 ))`, but it's a command, not an expression. The two are just used in different contexts.

Comment: @thatotherguy For example, `((++i))` to increment `i` works fine.

Comment: Not in the context where OP is using it

Comment: You can even write `((i%2))||printf '%d is even\n' "$i"`

Comment: What is an exit status?

Comment: After you run any command, look at the value of `$?`: that's the exit status of the previous command. It's generally used to determine if the command "succeeded"; zero means success, and any non-zero value is some sort of failure, with the means of specific non-zero values determined by the command itself.

Answer (score 5):

`$(( expression ))` is the syntax for evaluating an arithmetic expression, and replacing this syntax with the result of that expression. It's documented in the Bash Manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#Arithmetic-Expansion);

The syntax of arithmetic expressions is described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic). Putting `$` before variable names is optional, so you can also write it as `$(($i % 2))`.

You have to wrap it in two parentheses because `$(...)` already has a meaning, it's used for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution): `$(some command)` executes `some command` and is then replaced with the output of the command.

You don't need parentheses around `[ ... ]`. The normal way to write your `if` statement would be

```
if [ $((i % 2)) -eq 1 ]
```

You can also write it as

```
if (( i % 2 == 1 ))
```

`(( expression ))` evaluatees the arithmetic expression, and then sets its exit status depending on whether the result is zero or non-zero.

Comment: You could also write it as `(( i % 2 == 1 )) && echo $i` if you wanted to do away with the `if` altogether...

Comment: Yes, but I'm a big believer in `if`, so I rarely mention that myself.

Comment: I write makefiles, where `if`'s are a pain, but I can see your point.

Answer (score 0):

Since you *specify* `bash`, simplest is

```
for i in {1..99}
do  if ((i % 2)) 
    then echo $i
    fi
done
```

the `((i % 2))` will return i mod 2, which will always be zero or one. This particular construct behaves like a C-style boolean, so zero is false and anything else is true (the opposite behavior from `[[ ... ]]` which uses *return* code of zero to mean true/ok).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [`expr`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expr-command-in-linux-with-examples/):

```
for i in {1..99}
do
  num=`expr i % 2`
  if (( num == 1 ))
  then
      echo $i
  fi
done
```

Comment: `expr` is worse in every way than POSIX-standardized arithmetic syntax. It's slow (implemented by a separate executable that has to be invoked every time with stdout read over a FIFO). It doesn't allow C-like syntax. It's not any more standardized (`(( ))` isn't standard-mandated, but `$(( ))` _is_). And finally, I don't see how suggesting using something instead answers the question the OP asked.