# What does the $ symbol mean in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am a bit confused with the `$` symbol in bash.
Why does the first line of the code work while the second line gives an error??

```
echo $(($1 * 2))
echo (($1 * 2))
```

Does the `$` symbol work like a pointer?

And why does the first while loop not work while the second one does?

```
#giving error
n=1
while [$n -le 5]
do
    echo "Running $n time"
    ((n++))
done

#Not giving error
n=1
while [ $n -le 5 ]
do
    echo "Running $n time"
    (( n++ ))
done
```

Comment: `$` doesn't mean just one thing; it means different things in different contexts. `$(( ))` is syntax for a POSIX-compliant arithmetic _expression_. `(( ))` is non-POSIX / extended syntax for an arithmetic _statement_. You can't use a statement as an argument to another command.

Comment: See [Could you explain the syntax for math in a bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59759172/could-you-explain-the-syntax-of-math-in-a-bash-shell)

Comment: (and "why should anyone learn bash?" is **far** too broad and opinion-based of a question to be on-topic here).

Comment: `[` requires spaces for compatibility with the legacy `/usr/bin/[` binary (well, mostly a symlink to `test`), although `[ ... ]` has been (also) a Bash built-in construct for ages. You are using a mixture of Bash and legacy shell style. `for ((n = 1; n <= 5; ++n)); do echo "Running $((n)). time."; done`.

Comment: In general shell syntax, `$` indicates the beginning of some sort of expansion: `$var` or `${var}` expands to a variable's value; `$1`, `$2`, etc to parameters; `$(command)` to the output of the command; `$((expr))` to the result of an integer expression; `$$` to the PID of the shell; etc. Also, be aware that shell syntax is extremely context-dependent, which is to say that what something means generally depends on *where* it occurs. And spaces are important delimiters in shell syntax, so adding or removing them often completely changes the meaning of something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((...))` just evaluates and sets a return code.
`$((...))` does that as well, but also replaces itself with the string representing the result.

```
n=1
while ((n<=5)); do echo "Running: $(( n++ )) time(s)"; done
Running: 1 time(s)
Running: 2 time(s)
Running: 3 time(s)
Running: 4 time(s)
Running: 5 time(s)
```

Your error was here -

```
while [$n -le 5]
```

Spaces (or other similarly clarifying metacharacters) are required around the `[` operator, but not inside `((...))` where the more limited syntax is less ambiguous in general. Paste your code in at https://www.shellcheck.net/ and it will show you things like this in seconds, with explanations.

c.f. [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) for more info.